# How to find the equation of this curve from the data?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

I have the following data:

```
x        y
-------------
60      47.78
30      45.35
20      42.98
15      40.66
12      38.4
10      36.19
6       27.93
5       24.13
4       18.85
3       11.17
```

How can I find the equation of the line? I have plotted the graph and it looks like this:

[image: Graph]

I'm not sure what degree or type of curve this is. I have tried using Logger Pro to automatically find the best fit line but it doesn't get it. The closest I could get to is a Natural Exponent curve. This is what it is:

[image: Graph Autofit]

How can I find the equation of this curve?

Comment: If you have the feeling that something is logarithmic, plot is using a logarithmic scale. Then you can read out equation in an easier way.

Comment: @b00n heT  the problem here is that if it is (as plausible) a relationship of type $y=A-Bexp(-Cx)$, a logarithmic scale will be harmful...

Comment: That's also true.

Comment: I would advise you take the model "$Aexp(-Cx)+B$" after having dropped say the first 3 or 4 values and/or having imposed an asymptotic value $B=50$.

Comment: @JeanMarie So I should try the fit after the first 3 data points, I got that. I tried that and it seems worse. Here it is: http://imgur.com/a/1V54K. I lost you at "imposed an asymptotic value...". What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that it seems that there is an horizontal asumptote ("a ceiling") at $y=50$ or $y=52$ or something like that...

Comment: @JeanMarie Ahh, that makes sense because the y values are areas of some shapes inside a circle. The total area of the circle is 16pi = 50.27... So is there any way I could model and get the equation?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to optimize these test functions using different types of [sigmoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) :

1. $\displaystyle\quad A\arctan\left(\frac{x-B}C\right)$
   For $A=31.5,B=1.55,C=3,77\;$ I obtained :
   [image: arctan]
2. $\displaystyle\quad \frac {A\;x}{\sqrt{1+(x/B)^2}}$
   For $A=5.4,B=8.8\;$ I obtained :
   [image: 1/sqrt]

and others...

[Alpha's bestfit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20(3,11.17),(4,18.85),(5,24.13),(6,27.93),(10,36.19),(12,38.4),(15,40.66),(20,42.98),(30,45.35),(60,47.78)) didn't help much here...

Comment: How did you get to this equation?

Comment: Also, how come on Alpha's it shows different best fits?

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal: 1: by "visual recognition " : the function was increasing like a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t%28x%29.svg) and I tried some equations in mupad ($\tanh$ too but...). 2: Alpha tries different classical methods (polynomal, logarithmic...) and plots only the 3 bests (sorted by accuracy) I think.

Comment: I have just realised that there must be an asymptote at 16pi = 50.265... That is because the y values are areas of shapes inside a circle. Does this make anything easier?

Comment: @Lakshya Goyal: yes of course (as any additional constraint like crossing $(0,0)$ or having a precise tangent somewhere). In the [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t%28x%29.svg) hypothesis you'll have, in the $\arctan$ answer $\,A=16\pi\dfrac 2{\pi}=32\,$ instead of $A=31.5$ while for the inverse square root solution you'll have $A\;B=16\pi$ instead of $47.52$. Note that in both solutions I supposed that the inflection point was on the line $y=0$ (with an horizontal shift for the first one) they could be shifted too vertically by adding an overall constant

Comment: btw you'll obtain an horizontal shift for the second one by replacing both $\,x\,$ with $\,(x-C)$ (thus $A$ and $B$ are for vertical and horizontal scaling while $C$ will assume horizontal shift).

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal: of course this upper-bound is interesting too for non-sigmoid functions and, from the picture of your software, a fine idea would be to try it again but with the $(x,y)$ couples replaced by $(x,16\pi-y)$. You could then deduce that the function is decreasing like an exponential or a polynomial or whatever... (the constant $16$ of your $16\pi$ should be know accurately). Excellent continuation,

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a function with as much parameters as point, you won't find a perfect fit. Look for the best one into your Logger pro, it seems to do the job of parametrizing for you (I'd say you have some kind of log or $x^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha<1$).

If you don't want any of these models, choose a function $f(x,a_1,...,a_1)$ where $a_i$ are your parameters, and with your actual values of x, minimize

$ \min_{a_i} \sum_{\text{all }x}(f(x,a_1,..,a_n)-y)^2$